# jquery mobile with two navbars

Tags: jquery, mobile, navbar

I got navbar A in Page 1 and navbar B in Page 2,when I click the navbar B in page 2,navbar A in page 1 lost its focus,so when get back from page 2 to page 1,page 1 did not show anything because of the losing activity of navbar A.

In page 1's Header：

```
<div data-role = "navbar"  id = "mainHeaderNavbar>
  <ul>  
    <li><a data-id = "top" id = "menu-top" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist my-btn" >Top</a></li>  
    <li><a data-id = "sports" id = "menu-sports" class="my-btn">Sports</a></li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

In page 2's footer:

```
<div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top" data-id = "setfooter" id = "setPageNavbar">
        <ul> 
            <li><a data-id = "discuss" id = "discuss"  data-icon="plus" class="my-btn"></a></li>
            <li><a data-id = "download" id = "download" data-icon="arrow-d" class="my-btn"></a></li>    
        </ul>  
</div>
```

And in my javascript file I use this to listen to page 1's navbar events:

```
$(document).delegate('.ui-navbar a', 'click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');
    $('.content_div').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('data-id')).show();
});
```

As in Page 2's navbar:

```
$("#discuss").live("click",function()
```

Any ideas?Thanks.

Comment: We need to see some of your code to help you

Answer (score 0):

Apply `data-ajax="false` on the navbars..

For ex:-

```
<a href="index.html" data-ajax="false>Link</a>
```